# Proper http method(s) for serving static content

Tags: http

I apologize if there's an answer elsewhere.

I'm building a simple server and am now working on static file responses.  Should I refuse all http methods except GET when serving static content?  By static content I am referring to files stored on the file system on the server.

My immediate hunch is to only allow GET, but I want to make sure before locking it down.

What http method(s) should resolve static files of the form:
http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/baz.css?
Not necessarily requested through the browser, obviously.

Comment: GET is the default, yes. Don’t use others for simply serving content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All HTTP requests have a specific purpose. If you don't plan to implement that purpose or feature, block it with 405 Method Not Allowed.

For example, do you want to allow others update the files? You'll need `PUT` then. I'd recommend simply reading what the methods mean so you know what makes sense and what not.

Intuitively I think you probably only need `GET` and `HEAD`. I think it's good to respond to `OPTIONS` with a correct response as well.

Comment: In other words, he should choose the HTTP protocol based on the behavior of the call, rather than simply because it serves static content.

Comment: This is more of controller/router.  I have a "FLAT" router config and if the path matches, I plan on returning the content "as is" that is found on the file system, ignoring caching for the time being.  I leave it to the controller callbacks to supply the appropriate behavior.

Comment: I imagine this would be mostly for javascripts or css that pages request when they load, though I don't want to dictate how this is ultimately used.  However, responding to all methods that match the FLAT config seems silly to me.

Comment: @Dale I'm not really sure what to take from your comments. Is something unclear in my answer? Feel free to ask more!

Comment: No, you were very helpful.  I was just rubber ducking.  Thank you.